# How to split a string into a string and an integer?

Tags: python, string, split, integer

How do you split a string into a several strings in python. The string I am trying to split is in the format of:

`Variable 1`

and I would like to split it into:

`Variable = Variable`

`Number = 1`

Comment: Do you know that strings have a method called `split`?

Comment: You really need to run through a full Python tutorial or class; this is *very* simple string manipulation; you can't learn the basics piecemeal a StackOverflow question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split based on the space in the example you gave, unless you need a more generic approach.

```py
# set up your variable
my_var = "variable 1"

# You can split by the space in this instance, if all of your data will look the same
my_split = my_var.split(" ")

# prints variable
print(my_split[0])

# prints 1
print(my_split[1])
```